# How clean up activity task candidates properly?

Tags: java, spring, alfresco, activiti

It is needed to clean up (modify) `candidateGroups` and `candidateUsers` in task listener:

```
@Override
public void notify(DelegateTask delegateTask) {
    DelegateExecution execution = delegateTask.getExecution();
        Set<IdentityLink> candidates = delegateTask.getCandidates();
        for (IdentityLink candidate : candidates) {
            // ???
            delegateTask.deleteCandidateGroup(candidate.getGroupId());
            delegateTask.deleteCandidateUser(candidate.getUserId());
        }
}
```

The question is what to call? There are 2 different methods for deleting group and user. Method `candidate.getType()` can be helpfull for identifying usr or group, but `org.activiti.engine.task.IdentityLinkType` has another values:

```
public class IdentityLinkType {
    public static final String ASSIGNEE = "assignee";
    public static final String CANDIDATE = "candidate";
    public static final String OWNER = "owner";
    public static final String STARTER = "starter";
    public static final String PARTICIPANT = "participant";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve as the candidates will all be effectively "cleaned up" as soon as the task is completed. The only thing that is maintained in history is the task owner and assignee. Candidates are not collected in history.

That said, the identity link types allow users to participate in the process in different ways (i.e. owners can delegate, assignees are responsible for DOING the task, candidate is a potential assignee but must CLAIM the task and so forth).

Your code to "clean up" candidates is fine, but once again, is probably redundant once a task is claimed and completed.

Comment: First off all - if there is a method it should be used, no? ;) Seriously, originally task has `candidateGroup` but it can "come back" and assign to one user. Yes, there `candidate` can assign task to it sefl, but it is needed to assign task to some one else without waiting when he/she assign task to itselft.

Comment: Also this code is execute when task created. You can think about this like this: "create candidate pool or assign task directly to one user".

Comment: "Your code to "clean up" candidates is fine". So executing `deleteCandidateGroup` and `deleteCandidateUser` for one `IdentityLink` is ok?

Comment: You may delete candidates (users or groups) from a task at any time. In fact, it is a very standard practice to ADD candidates based on external conditions using a task listener. Ive never heard of candidates being deleted, but hell, it's just an entity relationship, so theres nothign to stop you doing it.

However, you need to do it on the Assign" event, not "create". I know, it seems backward, but "assign" is fired before "create".

Comment: `However, you need to do it on the Assign" event, not "create"` on `assign` event this does not work, only at `create` event.

Comment: Thanks Cherry, "assign" is called first and the task details are only partially populated. This is where you need to populate candidates dynamically, however you are likely correct, the candidates will not be available until the create event, thanks for lettingme know, always something to learn.